# How to avoid complicated conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a component that updates information about a product.
If the component is not in edit mode then I display information as ready only (just text)
but if the component is in edit mode, then I need to load a list of availalble units.
then I would display it as editable (text boxes and select box)

so I need to distinguish a couple of states here.

if control is not editable then render as read only
if control is editable but units not loaded then load units and display loader
if control is editable and units loaded then display as editable
if loading units errored, display the error message
if the user clicked on save, then display loader
if saving is done, display as non editable
if saving errored, display the error message and keep it editable

Feels like a smell to me and as I am not proficient in React, what would be the best approach to handle this situation?
Here a sample of my rendering logic.

```
 if (
    (editMode &&
    availableUnitsFetchStatus === AvailableUnitsFetchStatus.PENDING)
    ||
    (editMode &&
      updateProductStatus === ProductUpdateStatus.PENDING)
  ) {
    return (
      <Card
        shadow="sm"
        p="lg"
        radius="md"
        withBorder
        w={340}
        h={340}
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Loader />
      </Card>
    );
  }

  if (
    (editMode &&
    availableUnitsFetchStatus ===
      AvailableUnitsFetchStatus.UNITS_FAILED_FETCHING)
      ||
      (
        editMode &&
        updateProductStatus === ProductUpdateStatus.PRODUCT_UPDATE_FAILED
      )
  ) {
     notifications.show({
          title: 'Default notification',
          message: 'Hey there, your code is awesome! ',
        })       
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to use guard conditions first and then render the main "thing".

So, you have multiple state values, effect for unit loading, handle for save and render conditions. See example here.

```
// sample component
const EditableCard = () => {
  const [editable, setEditable] = useState(true)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState('')
  const [units, setUnits] = useState(null)

  // this will load units on didMount, 
  // if you want to load them differently, 
  // you can pass inputs to useEffect and call fetch with condition
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)

    fetchUnits().then((data) => {
      setLoading(false)
      setUnits(data)
    })
  }, [])

  // this handle you call from onClick submit button event
  const handleSave = (data) => {
    setLoading(true)
    saveData(data).then((result) => {
      setLoading(false)
      setEditable(false)
    }).catch((e) => {
      setLoading(false)
      setError(e.toString())
    })
  }

  // guard conditions, if not editable, render the read only state
  if (!editable) {
    return <ReadOnly />
  }

  // show loader
  if (loading) {
    return <Loader />
  }


  // the main component render (editable state)
  return <Card>...editable content...</Card>
}
```

Comment: I must say that React is messy, very hard to follow the code.

Comment: No, it's not, it is up to you how you write it, you can write custom hooks for the state and effects. Functions for handles, etc. And that what you want to do is not for single component :)

Comment: state is what makes it less readable, because there is no sequence, at least not so obvious.